# Frame/clip grabs using Java from a network video camera/adapter (no activex)

Tags: java, video

I'm interested in doing image processing in Java with frames collected from a network video adapter.  The first challenge is finding network video adapters/cameras which don't require an ActiveX control for PTZ control and therefore require IE.  Then the issue is how to do still image grabs from network video adapters which only make MP4 available.

Does anyone know of some Java friendly network video cameras and adapters?

Anyone know of some Java code to control PTZ on a network camera?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways in Java that I know of.  The first (and the one I current recommend) is the [LTI-Civil](http://lti-civil.org/) project.  The second is to use [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) which uses FFmpeg webcam code behind the scenes.